# How to solve Unknow Field Error in Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

I am building a project a project by Django 2.0.2. What I want to do is making one of the fieldsets in admin page change automatically according to the database. Here is part of my code:

```
models.py
class Product(BaseModel):
    number=model.IntergerField("Food", null=True, blank=True, help_text="Food")

    @property
    def number(self):
        return 10 #just return a number for testing

admin.py
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=("number")    
    fieldsets=(('<h1>Food</h1>'), {'fields':('number')})
```

When I refresh the admin page, it shows "Unkown fields (number) specified for Product. Check fieldset attribute of class ProductAdmin". I am new to Django and not sure about what goes wrong. In the admin.py, I have added "number" field but the error still exist. How can I solve it? Many Thanks and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number` is *not* a field, it is a *property*. You can add this to the `readonly_fields`:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('number',)
    readonly_fields = ('number',)
    fieldsets=(('<h1>Food</h1>'), {'fields':('number')})
```

You should also add a `short_description` to your property, like:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    number=model.IntergerField("Food", null=True, blank=True, help_text="Food")

    # no decorator
    def number(self):
        return 10 #just return a number for testing
    number.short_description = "The number"
    number = property(number)
```

as is [documented in the `ModelAdmin` options section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).